# Data file seemingly too large with wine and openBUGS

Tags: r, wine, openbugs

I have recently started trying to do some bayesian modelling with OpenBUGS and R using `R2OpenBUGS`.

I followed a great link for installing wine and OpenBUGS by David Eagles and the schools example posted there worked fine.

I then tried to run some code I had and kept getting an error after the `the model is syntactically correct` telling me the data was not loading properly.

After a few days of troubleshooting this it seems that when the datafile is above a certain length the top bit (where you traditionally highlight `list` in OpenBUGS to load data) is lost and the data cannot be loaded by OpenBUGS.

[A screenshot of my OpenBUGS program with the loaded data where the list section has been cut off](https://www.dropbox.com/s/chznfsol6gdjuxu/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-09%20at%2012.00.20.png?dl=0)

This picture shows that at the top of my data.txt file there is no longer a `list{` which is basically stopping all of my attempts to run the model.

To confirm this I have ran the example of a [simple linear regression](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/1935_652d6fb17d7941c4b91bbbc5a22d4494.html) where I set the number of points to 1000 and then to 100:

```
 # Load in paths for running OpenBUGS through wine
source("/Users/dp323/Desktop/R/scripts/Where_is_my_OpenBUGS.R")  

# set up model
linemodel <- function() {
  for (j in 1:N) {
    Y[j] ~ dnorm(mu[j], tau)  ## Response values Y are Normally distributed
    mu[j] <- alpha + beta * (x[j] - xbar)  ## linear model with x values centred
  }
  ## Priors
  alpha ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  beta ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  tau ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
  sigma <- 1/sqrt(tau)
}

# set up data ####
linedata <- list(Y = c(1:100), x = c(1:100), N = 100, xbar = 3)

# set initial values ####
lineinits <- function() {
  list(alpha = 1, beta = 1, tau = 1)
}

# run bugs ####
lineout <- bugs(data = linedata, inits = lineinits, parameters.to.save = c("alpha", "beta", "sigma"), model.file = linemodel, n.chains = 1, n.iter = 10000, OpenBUGS.pgm = OpenBUGS.pgm, WINE = WINE, WINEPATH = WINEPATH, useWINE = T, debug = T)
```

The model runs great when `linedata <- list(Y = c(1:100), x = c(1:100), N = 100, xbar = 3)` but falls apart at the loading in data stage when `linedata <- list(Y = c(1:1000), x = c(1:1000), N = 1000, xbar = 3)`.

I have exhausted a google search of limits of data file size on wine and OpenBUGS and not found anything helpful.

Anyone have any suggestions of what to try/where to start/experience of this before?

Comment: Afraid I can't help directly, but JAGS is very similar to BUGS, runs on Nix, and works well with R via rjags. http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks. I have tried jags this but the code I am trying to emulate uses the `cut()` function which jags does not currently support. Maybe in time I will work out how to alter the model but for now would like to keep it as it is.

Comment: Oh, interesting! Here's some discussion that I imagine you've already come across:
https://martynplummer.wordpress.com/2014/01/05/mcmski-2014/
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/missing-values-in-response-variable-in-jags